# How to find version of a software installed in ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-12.04

Is there any universal command that I can use in the console, for example how to find the mysql version ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `dpkg` to get that info:

```
dpkg -l mysql-server | grep -E "^ii" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3
```

This will give you the installed version of the `mysql-server` package.

If a package is not installed, it will print out "No packages found matching mysql-server." instead.

Answer (score 8):

Almost all programs that can be run in the command line have a `--version` option.

For example:

```
git --version
ls --version
```

The format of their output is nowhere near standard though. Some make it easier to parse, some (often) include a little information about the license.